# Squid forward SSL certificate with passphrase

Tags: proxy, https, squid

I have a HTTPS server that expects the client to provide a certificate. This cert uses a passphrase. Everything works fine. But if I use SQUID as my proxy then the authentication fails and squid returns a 503.

Is there anything special I would need to configure in squid? I couldn't find anything in the docs.

I'm getting the following in the squid cache.log

```
fwdNegotiateSSL: Error negotiating SSL connection on FD 15: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure (1/0/0)
```

-- EDIT--

Well, I found the configuration I needed  to add and now it's working as expected:

```
sslpassword_program /etc/squid/program.sh
sslproxy_client_key /etc/squid/keys/cert.pem
```

I put my cert.pem into the /keys folder. Then program.sh is a very simple program that prints the passphrase. This is all it has:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "mypassphrase"
```

Restarted squid and now it's working!

Comment: Have you configured that certificate and passphrase into squid?

Comment: I haven't. Should I do it with http_port ? My understanding was that the cert in that directive is for the origin client and not for the destination server. Also couldn't find any "passphrase" option on the squid docs.

Comment: Is your squid proxy in ssl bump mode?  Or are your clients configured to point at it, such that HTTPS happens over an HTTP CONNECT?